# When adding the controls through the storyboard, the properties are not applied correctly

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextfield, uistoryboard, propertyinfo

In my case, I added a UITextField in the storyboard and I tried to apply some properties through the property window. I enabled the Secure Text Entry property in the property window and I changed the text using the text property in the property window. When changing the text through text property, the UITextField in the storyboard doesn't display the password text rather it displayed the text which I typed in the text property. Can anyone please tell why it is not displaying the password character even though when the Secure Text Entry is enabled in the property window. For the reference, I have attached a video describing the issue which I have faced when adding control through a storyboard. Please download the video using the below link and provide me a better solution for the query.

Video Link: [Demo Video](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/StoryBoardIssue_Demo.mov1525254545)

Comment: I have checked this , it should be an phenomenon not shows correctly when modifying Secure Text Proerety . However , it can not affect the app running correctlly . By the way , I have submitted it in Github , you also can follow it up there .
 https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8178

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on XCode as well. This is a bug in VS for Mac's "iOS Designer".

When you run your app though, the text field will show secure characters, so you won't have to worry.

Alternatively, you can just right click on the Storyboard and Open with the native XCode Interface Builder instead, and edit the storyboard therein.

You should file a bug to VS for Mac for this!